# C# open discord link without opening browser

Tags: c#, .net, rider

long time ago the followed method `discord://invites/{code}` worked but nowadays doesn't work. is there a alternative method or at least hints of so?
I tried looking at discord's api might got some clue heard from friends they did similar to it using websockets.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting Discord as the default application for the `discord://` protocol in Windows 10 settings. (Though I haven't tried it)

Comment: It is set by default once discord installed.